# Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $C$ be the closed,piecewise curve figured by traveling in straight lines between the points $(-2,1),(-2,-3),(1,-1),(1,5)$ and back to $(-2,1)$, in that order. Use Green's Theorem to evaluate the integral:

$$\int_C (2 x y)dx + (x y^2)dy$$

So far I have used Green's Theorem and calculated the vector form of Green's Theorem. Since the region enclosed by C is y-simple, we can set up the double integral to first integrate in terms of $y(x)$ then $x$. However, I am not getting the same answer as the book.

Comment: I was just wondering if how I am approaching the question wrong or if its simply a calculation erorr

Comment: What answer did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region in question is a trapezoid, bounded by the lines $x=-2$, $x=1$, $y=(4/3) x+(11/3)$, and $y=(2/3)x-(5/3)$.  Use Green's theorem to convert the line integral to an integral over the area of the region:

$$\oint_{\partial D} (P\, dx+Q\, dy) = \iint_D dx\,dy \: \left ( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)$$

To set up the area integral, take the derivatives and use those bounds:

$$\int_{-2}^1 dx \: \int_{(2/3)x-(5/3)}^{(4/3) x+(11/3)} dy \: (y^2-2 x)$$

You should be able to work this out.

Comment: For the line y=2x+3 I got something slightly different, however these are the steps that I took to get an answer. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Did you get $(4/3) x+(11/3)$?

Comment: Yes that was my upper bound for y(x)

Comment: Very sorry for the error then.

Comment: It's fine, it happens once in a while!