# Green's Theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question I can't really solve using Green's theorem for some reason.

There's a path C that's closed, it's a piecewise smooth curve formed by the traveling in straight lines between (-2, 1), (-2, -3), (1, -1), (1, 5) and back to (-2, 1).

We're supposed to use Green's theorem to evaluate:
$$
\int_C (2xy)dx + (xy^2)dy
$$

So I applied Green's theorem and got:
$$
\int\int_D (y^2 - 2x)dxdy
$$

But the problem is, I can't find the region to evaluate the integral I got. The region doesn't look like a square/rectangle, and it's sort of uneven so I can't really find an equation that would best define it.

Any sort of hints?

Comment: I answered this already: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338576/greens-theorem/338645#338645